# Python code: explain please

Tags: python

```
first_num = raw input ("Please input first number. ")
sec_num = raw input (" Please input second number:")
answer = into( first_num) +into( sec_num)

print " Now I will add your two numbers : ", answer

print " Pretty cool. huh ?
print " Now I'll  count backwards from ",answer

counter = answer
while (counter >=0):
    print counter
    counter = counter-1
print " All done !"
```

I think the first half in a command to add first and second numbers to get sum and the second half is a command to return to start or zero out. I don't know python language.

Comment: Atleast put the properly formatted code, also what is the question here?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try to run the code first and play with it to understand it. The code is simple; the first half take two user inputs and add them to each other then it displays the result.

```
first_num = input("Please input first number:") # get first number input
sec_num = input("Please input second number:")  # get second number input
answer = int(first_num) +int(sec_num)           # add up int values of the numbers
print(" Now I will add your two numbers : ", answer)    # display answer
```

As for the second half it takes a number from which it counters downward till zero

```
print("Now I'll count backwards from ", answer)
counter = answer           # set counter start value
while(counter >=0):        
     print(counter)        # display counter value on each iteration
     counter = counter-1   # decrement counter value on each iteration
print(" All done !)
```

I changed your code cause your lines were a bit messy and some incorrect. This version by me works on python3 and **NOT** python2.7. If you want to learn python I advise you to start with [code academy python tutorial](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/python)

Comment: Thx you da man.  I did have some probs w/ posting. The sequence got out of order. Thanks again